# XQuartz has a black background with all apps

Tags: big-sur, apple-silicon, xquartz

I'm running M1 Big Sur with Xquartz. For some reason, the background of all apps run with Xquartz is black (and it sometimes flickers). It seems that XQuartz is trying to help out by forcing a "Dark Mode". Why does that happen?

Comment: Do you mean the wallpaper, or the theme of the apps themselves?  An X11 app is going to be themed according to the toolkit it's using, whether GTK/QuickTime/Xwidgets.

Comment: The "wallpaper" -- it's like a black overlay over the apps that is unrelated to the theme of the apps themselves.

Comment: Sounds like it's not running rootless.  Also, which Xquartz, from what source?

Comment: Xquartz 2.8.1 from the official website. What do you mean "rootless"? It's not running in a virtual desktop though, it's running as separate apps. I'll see if I can attach a picture.

Comment: Interesting -- whenever I try to make a screenshot, it goes away, if I keep my cursor still, it goes away, but if I move my mouse, the black comes back.

Comment: If one of the X11 applications does not have focus, is the "black" there?  You're still not clear on what that even is... a halo around an app, or a pseudo-window the apps are running within.

Comment: Basically: you know that for GTK apps, "dark mode" is a dark grey color? X11 makes all those areas pure black.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Other have the same problem: https://github.com/XQuartz/XQuartz/issues/31

Comment: Ah, ok. This is a widespread problem -- thought it was just me.